# Django formset of inline formsets

Tags: django, nested, formset

I have the following models:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Questionpart(models.Model):
    TYPES = (
        ('TX', 'Text'),
        ('AN', 'Answer'),
    )
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, null=True, blank=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=TYPES) # defines which QuestionPart_ will be used as additional data
    step_number = models.IntegerField()

class Questionpart_answer(models.Model):
    questionpart = models.ForeignKey(Questionpart)
    #other answer specific fields

class Questionpart_text(models.Model):
    questionpart = models.ForeignKey(Questionpart)
    #other text specific fields, there are a few more like this
```

I already have a form which handles adding/editing question, but each question is made of several texts/answer (and other types which are omitted here). I want to be able to add/delete steps when editing question (on one page).

I've created a formset - `QuestionPartFormset` and in `QuestionPartModelForm` I've added fields from the corresponding model to this form according to type. This seems really ugly. There has to be a better way!!

I was thinking about a formset of `inline_formsets`...
I would appreciate any suggestions! Are my models defined ok? Shouldn't each type be inherited from `QuestionPart` model eg: (I think Django creates a foreign key in this case too, but at least I would have one superclass):

```
class QuestionPart_answer(QuestionPart):
```

Comment: Not related to answer. `question_id = models.ForeignKey(...)` will result in column name `question_id_id`. Probably better to omit `_id` suffix in your model field names since Django takes care of that. Docs - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#database-representation

Comment: Thanks I'm aware of that